# Rider Unit Test: Export Results with RunTimes

Tags: automated-tests, export-to-csv, rider

I regularly use a suite of pertinent "Unit" Tests as a Performance Testing Framework.

Sometimes I want to be able to run it repeatedly on different commits to re-check how the performance has evolved (or to double check the consequences of my rebasing).

Rider has a good test view where it shows the test run time ... but I'd like to be able to copy that data, quickly. (e.g. to look through and document the results whilst the next run is happening)

Is there any way to export the test run results, along with their run time, to some sort of text/data file?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm not aware of such a feature. However, I would advise against inferring the performance from the duration of the tests. Instead, I’d rather use a dedicated tool such as BenchmarkDotNet.

Comment: If I were worrying about the ms run time of low level code I would agree. But since I'm talking about "does this large update process run in >10minutes, 2-3 minutes, 25 seconds, or <2 seconds?" ... the Test run-time is entirely adequate.